# DIR to extract a text directory text dump along with file attributes : "Last Edited by" "Last Edited"

Tags: cmd, dos, dir

I'm attempting to use the dir command to extract the directory structure along with file attributes such as "Last Edited by" "Last modified".

What I've got so far is

dir /s /b DirPath > textfile.txt

I'd like to use the /b as I do not require the unecessary header information.

Thanks in Advance.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I can think of to your requirement:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b DirPath') do @echo %~ti,%i
```

Note that you have to double the percents when using this in a script.

It iterates over all files/directories under DirPath and prints their last-modified timestamp and the name of the file/directory, as a CSV.

Not sure what you mean by "Last Edited by", I don't think that kind of metadata is stored on Windows (or Unix?).

---

**Edit:** I haven't done a lot of work with VBS before, but it looks like this works:

```
Set s = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
s.Run("cmd /c (for /f ""delims="" %i in ('dir /s /b .') do @echo %~ti,%i)& pause")
```

I added the `pause` to keep the popup DOS box alive (executed it via `cscript test.vbs`) so I could verify the output, but you can obviously get rid of that if you're redirecting the output to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am currently trying to call the shell from within VBA, get a text dump of the directory structure and save it as a text file. I am using the following code to achieve that.  Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /C" & "dir /s /b dirPath > text file", vbNormalFocus). The code you have provided works a charm but i'm not sure how I'd modify it to fit in with my VBA code. Your help is much appreciated.